# Python Pymoo - get an import error when copy and paste tutorial code

Tags: python, optimization, pymoo

I am a Python beginner. Trying to follow a **getting started** tutorial of a multi-objective optimization algoritm https://pymoo.org/getting_started/part_2.html

I have installed pymoo according to the installation instructions:

```
pip install -U pymoo
```

Everything works fine up to the paragraph **Define a Termination Criterion**

I imput the code:

```
from pymoo import get_termination
```

### **ERROR**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10384/2370239780.py in <module>
      1 #Define a Termination Criterion
      2 
----> 3 from pymoo import get_termination
      4 

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_termination' from 'pymoo' (C:\Users\musae\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymoo\__init__.py)
```

---

The same things happens when I imput

```
from pymoo.problems import get_problem
```

from that **example** of NSGA2 algorithm https://pymoo.org/algorithms/moo/nsga2.html#nb-nsga2

**ERROR**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_24508/113033208.py in <module>
      1 from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
----> 2 from pymoo.problems import get_problem
      3 from pymoo.optimize import minimize
      4 from pymoo.visualization.scatter import Scatter
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_problem' from 'pymoo.problems' (C:\Users\musae\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymoo\problems\__init__.py)
```

---

Have I installed it wrong? Why do I get those errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `from pymoo.problems import get_problem` use `from pymoo.problems.multi import *` .

And for get_problem use problem instead. As an example:

`get_problem("zdt1").pareto_front()`

Should be converted to:

`ZDT1().pareto_front()`

Answer (score 0):

I also came across the first error of unable to inport get_termination, using
`from pymoo.factory import get_termination` works for me.